# VB.NET - Find current timezone, then convert to Pacific

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I tried searching around for the code, but I didn't have too much luck. I found little snippets and I know how to convert current time to UTC, but I just really want to know how to get the current time zone, then convert the time to pacific.

I have many users that use my software all the way from california to maine. So I need to find out what timezone they are in, then convert it to pacific no matter where they are so I can accurately compare the local time to my servers time.

Comment: I seem to remember the easiest strategy for this is convert to UTC and then convert to the local timezone. e.g. Maine -> UTC -> California. (Unable to confirm this at the moment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the TimeZoneInfo class to convert time zones for you:

```
    Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    MessageBox.Show(now.ToString())

    Dim pacificNow = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"))
    MessageBox.Show(pacificNow.ToString())
```

You can read more about the TimeZones and the Ids on [MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx)

Comment: I feel like an idiot. For some reason when I saw this code originally on a different post on here I thought where it says "Pacific Standard Time" that you had to manually put in your time zone. thanks for the clarification!